# setInterval and useState problems while building a timer clock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

**Description:** So I am building a planning feature for my room meeting app. I have a timer clock and a timeline with stops.
[image]

If the timeclock reaches 00:02, then the respective text (00:02) will turn red, that is simply it

**Problem**: The timeline didn't work the way I expected ( I think it is about the useState delay )

**My approach**: so I have a sorted array of stops ( called timeline ) and the timer clock time. I will create a state called stopIndex with the default value of 0. And then, for each time the timer clock change, I will check if the current time > timeline[stopIndex] => stopIndex++. In other words, if the current time go pass the stop time, we will move on to the next stop.

So this is how I code the timer clock

```
  const [time, setTime] = useState({hours:"", minutes:"", seconds:""});
 //--time logic--
  const getTime = () => {
    const time = Date.now() - Date.parse(room?.startedTime); // get the time now
    const hours = Math.floor((time / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    const minutes = Math.floor((time / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    const seconds = Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60);
      
    // display clock logic
    if (hours < 10) {
      setTime((prev) => ({ ...prev, hours: `0${hours}` }));
    } else {
      setTime((prev) => ({ ...prev, hours: `${hours}` }));
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
      setTime((prev) => ({ ...prev, minutes: `0${minutes}` }));
    } else {
      setTime((prev) => ({ ...prev, minutes: `${minutes}` }));
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
      setTime((prev) => ({ ...prev, seconds: `0${seconds}` }));
    } else {
      setTime((prev) => ({ ...prev, seconds: `${seconds}` }));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // checking if the room has started and record the time at that momment
    if (room.startedTime) {
      const interval = setInterval(() => getTime(), 1000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [room.startedTime]);
  //--time logic--
```

The codes below is for checking if the timer reaches the stop time.

```
// the miliseconds of stops in timeline
const [timeStop, setTimeStop] = useState(0);
// an array of stops, which contained information about stops
const [timeline, setTimeline] = useState([]);
const [stopIndex, setStopIndex] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
// I convert the timer clock time to miliseconds for easy comparision
    const miliseconds = time.minutes * 60 * 1000 + time.seconds * 1000;

    if (
      miliseconds > timeStop &&
      stopIndex < timeline.length - 1 &&
      timeStop != 0
    ) {
      setStopIndex((prev) => prev + 1);
      // I stored the stopTime in string like "00:00" so I have to convert it into number
      const hours = timeline[stopIndex + 1].time.substring(0, 2);
      const minutes = timeline[stopIndex + 1].time.substring(3, 5);
      // next timeStop value to compare
      setTimeStop(hours * 60 * 60 * 1000 + minutes * 60 * 1000);
    } 
// or If the timer clock have just started to count, I will set the timeStop value to the second stop value in the timeline ( the first value is actually "00:00" so we don't need to compare with that )

else if (
      timeStop === 0
    ) {
      setStopIndex(0);
      const hours = timeline[1].time.substring(0, 2);
      const minutes = timeline[1].time.substring(3, 5);
      setTimeStop(hours * 60 * 60 * 1000 + minutes * 60 * 1000);
    }
    console.log(stopIndex);
    console.log(miliseconds);
    console.log(timeStop);
  }, [time]);
```

Here is what were logged out
[image]

Hmm I thought there were some kinds of useState delay here that made the stopIndex count two times consecutively.
How can I fix this problem？or do you guys have any solution that is better than this? thank you！

Comment: Should the dependency of your effect be `room.startedTime` instead of `room`? I'd also consider moving all of `getTime` inside of the `useEffect`, otherwise it's really easy to lose track of the other dependencies

Comment: You'll have a _much_ better time if the times in your timeline are just `Date`s/timestamps/minutes-after-midnight and you format them into the `HH:MM` format only later.

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured it out. The problem was indeed actually `*useState*` delay. I read on the doc about `useState` and found this [useState old value problem](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value). And then I applied the solution.

```
 const nextIndex = stopIndex + 1;
  setStopIndex(nextIndex);
  if (nextIndex < timeline.length - 1) {
    const hours = timeline[nextIndex + 1].time.substring(0, 2);
    const minutes = timeline[nextIndex + 1].time.substring(3, 5);
    setTimeStop(hours * 60 * 60 * 1000 + minutes * 60 * 1000);
  }
```

I stored the old value in `newIndex` and used it as the new `stopIndex`. There was no delay here, the problem was solved